# Far away objects projected in ARKit

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I can project nodes in ARKit but if they are outside of the 1'000 meter radius (the `zFar` property of the `SCNCamera`) then they don't show up in my scene. What are the strategies to overcome this? Change projection ? Project them on the 1km "sphere" that surounds the camera ?

Comment: `zFar` is 100 meters.

Answer (score 1):

You may create 2D or 3D "hints" which are semantical references for distant objects so that they just tell you there are some real objects in that direction. You may show distance to referenced above each reference.
Anyway, ARKit is not good enough for tracking objects on long distances.
Probably GPS tracking would be more suitable.